# R for loop: For all groups of rows with the same value in column, do

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I would love some help understanding the syntax needed to do a certain calculation in R.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a b c
1 1 0
2 1 1
3 1 0
4 2 0
5 2 0
6 3 1
7 3 0
8 3 0
9 4 0
```

and I want to create a new column "d" that has a value of 1 if (and only if) any of the values in column "c" equal 1 *for each group of rows that have the same value in column "b."*  Otherwise (see rows 4,5 and 9) column "d" gives 0.

```
a b c d
1 1 0 1
2 1 1 1
3 1 0 1
4 2 0 0
5 2 0 0
6 3 1 1
7 3 0 1
8 3 0 1
9 4 0 0
```

Can this be done with a for loop? If so, any advice on how to write that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `dplyr`, `df %>% group_by(b) %>% mutate(d = as.numeric(any(c == 1)))`, or in base R `df$d <- ave(df$c, df$b, FUN = function(x){as.numeric(any(x == 1))})`

Comment: with `data.table`: `setDT(df)[, d := (any(c)==1)*1, by = b]`

Comment: Thanks you alistaire - the dplyr way works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a loop:

```
# adding the result col
dat <- data.frame(dat, d = rep(NA, nrow(dat)))

# iterate over group
for(i in unique(dat$b)){
  # chek if there is a one for 
  # each group
  if(any(dat$c[dat$b == i] == 1))
     dat$d[dat$b == i] <- 1
  else
    dat$d[dat$b == i] <- 0
}
```

of course the data.table solutions is more elegant ;)

Comment: Thanks for giving me a loop code, but I'm glad everyone let me know of the short options. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table`

```
setDT(df)
df[, d := as.integer(any(c == 1L)), b]
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in base R (using the same general function as the dat.table method `any`), you can use `ave`:

```
df$d <- ave(cbind(df$c), df$b, FUN=function(i) any(i)==1)
```